# Promise и повторные вызовы одного обещания

Tags: javascript, promise

Вопрос может быть элементарный, но на всякий случай задам для достоверности.

Допустим, у нас есть promise (реализация `$q`):

```
var foo1 = $q.defer().resolve(data).then(function(data) {
  // Do something

},
function(err) {
  // Handling error
}
);
```

И где-то в коде мы вызываем его несколько раз:

```
foo1.then(function(data) {
  // Do something1
});
...
foo1.then(function(data) {
  // Do something2
});
```

Такое разрешается? Или требуется обязательно chain-структура `then().then().then()` или обертка в новый `promise`?

Comment: @apiya, Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш ответ ответом (или комментарием). Тогда мы сможем отметить его как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментария:

---

Отвечаю на свой вопрос.
Все же лень взяла свое и заглянул в стандарт [promise A+](https://promisesaplus.com/):

> then may be called multiple times on the same promise.